# Setting default value in select options in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, select

I'm trying to pass through a value and text to populate the `select` options dropdown. The value and text are being passed but the text is not displaying correctly.

**Code for `select`:**

```
<select id="ProjectList" class="select2" style="width:100%" select2 options="options.ProjectsSelect2Options" ajaxcall="false">
                <option value="?" selected="selected" label="ProjectName">{{options.ProjectName}}</option>
            </select>
```

**See image below of how the text being passed is displaying:**
[image: Display issue]

Is it possible to set a custom text in the curly braces as text `<option>{{**Custom text passed as variable**}}</option>`

Comment: can you show your array which you are using?

Comment: how about this code?
https://plnkr.co/edit/ObKpRPuMdnaX4NSb7yyj?p=preview

Comment: @HaegyunJung thanks will try to implement it and see if it works.